# Create a Map in Golang from database Rows

Tags: database, go, variadic-functions

Basically after doing a query I'd like to take the resulting rows and produce a `[]map[string]interface{}`, but I do not see how to do this with the API since the `Rows.Scan()` function needs a specific number of parameters matching the requested number of columns (and possibly the types as well) to correctly obtain the data.

Again, I'd like to generalize this call and take any query and turn it into a `[]map[string]interface{}`, where the map contains column names mapped to the values for that row.

This is likely very inefficient, and I plan on changing the structure later so that `interface{}` is a struct for a single data point.

How would I do this using just the database/sql package, or if necessary the database/sql/driver package?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look at using [sqlx](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx), which can do this a little more easily than the standard database/sql library:

```
places := []Place{}
err := db.Select(&places, "SELECT * FROM place ORDER BY telcode ASC")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf(err)
    return
}
```

You could obviously replace `[]Place{}` with a `[]map[string]interface{}`, but where possible it is better to use a struct if you know the structure of your database. You won't need to undertake any type assertions as you might on an `interface{}`.

Comment: "You could obviously replace []Place{} with a []map[string]interface"... are you sure about that? Have you tested it? I'm trying to use a map and I get an error: "Error Destination must be a struct type."

Comment: @rem7 Must be a limitation of that library, then. It's very rare you want to use a map for a DB select, though: you should nearly always know the structure.

Comment: I don't think it's very rare to use map. The reason why I want to use map is that I don't want to use struct. I don't want to make any assumption about the fields of the query result set.

Comment: If it matters to anyone, `structs` are cheaper and safer than `maps`. https://talks.golang.org/2012/10things.slide#2

Comment: Sure, they're cheaper and safer, but that doesn't mean they're objectively "better" because... they're entirely different beasts. Maps allow you to store arbitrary keys and values, which is needed when you have... arbitrary data, which is possible when building applications meant for SQL querying, for example. Structs are just contiguous memory, like an array, so of course, they're "cheaper" :)

Comment: While the answer might be true, I'm not sure if it answers asked question

Comment: sqlx just provide a way automatically scan **each row** into a map, check this: http://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/#altScanning

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used it (yet), but I believe the "common" way to do what you are asking (more or less) is to use [gorp](https://github.com/coopernurse/gorp).

Now 10 years later: Yeah, don't do that! Use [sqlc](https://sqlc.dev) or sqlx.

Comment: [sqlx](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx) will also fit that requirement. Allows you to easily scan into a slice of maps/structs. Note that structs are better if you know your DB structure: you can ensure type-safety at compile-time.

Comment: Yes, sqlx looks nice too. I couldn't remember the name yesterday.  The author also has a (work in progress) companion to sqlx called [modl](https://github.com/jmoiron/modl).

Comment: This should probably have been a comment since it just recommends a tool instead of answering OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a struct that maintains the map key to the position of the []interface{} slice. By doing this, you do not need to create a predefined struct. For example:

```
IDOrder: 0
IsClose: 1
IsConfirm: 2
IDUser: 3
```

**Then, you can use it like this:**

```
  // create a fieldbinding object.
  var fArr []string
  fb := fieldbinding.NewFieldBinding()

  if fArr, err = rs.Columns(); err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }

  fb.PutFields(fArr)

  //
  outArr := []interface{}{}

  for rs.Next() {
    if err := rs.Scan(fb.GetFieldPtrArr()...); err != nil {
      return nil, err
    }

    fmt.Printf("Row: %v, %v, %v, %s\n", fb.Get("IDOrder"), fb.Get("IsConfirm"), fb.Get("IDUser"), fb.Get("Created"))
    outArr = append(outArr, fb.GetFieldArr())
  }
```

**Sample output:**

```
Row: 1, 1, 1, 2016-07-15 10:39:37 +0000 UTC
Row: 2, 1, 11, 2016-07-15 10:42:04 +0000 UTC
Row: 3, 1, 10, 2016-07-15 10:46:20 +0000 UTC
SampleQuery: [{"Created":"2016-07-15T10:39:37Z","IDOrder":1,"IDUser":1,"IsClose":0,"IsConfirm":1},{"Created":"2016-07-15T10:42:04Z","IDOrder":2,"IDUser":11,"IsClose":0,"IsConfirm":1},{"Created":"2016-07-15T10:46:20Z","IDOrder":3,"IDUser":10,"IsClose":0,"IsConfirm":1}]
```

Please see the full example below or at [fieldbinding](https://github.com/junhsieh/goexamples/tree/master/fieldbinding):

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "database/sql"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

import (
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "github.com/junhsieh/goexamples/fieldbinding/fieldbinding"
)

var (
    db *sql.DB
)

// Table definition
// CREATE TABLE `salorder` (
//   `IDOrder` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
//   `IsClose` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
//   `IsConfirm` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
//   `IDUser` int(11) NOT NULL,
//   `Created` datetime NOT NULL,
//   `Changed` datetime NOT NULL,
//   PRIMARY KEY (`IDOrder`),
//   KEY `IsClose` (`IsClose`)
// ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

func main() {
    var err error

    // starting database server
    db, err = sql.Open("mysql", "Username:Password@tcp(Host:Port)/DBName?parseTime=true")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error()) // Just for example purpose. You should use proper error handling instead of panic
    }

    defer db.Close()

    // SampleQuery
    if v, err := SampleQuery(); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", err.Error())
    } else {
        var b bytes.Buffer

        if err := json.NewEncoder(&b).Encode(v); err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("SampleQuery: %v\n", err.Error())
        }

        fmt.Printf("SampleQuery: %v\n", b.String())
    }
}

func SampleQuery() ([]interface{}, error) {
    param := []interface{}{}

    param = append(param, 1)

    sql := "SELECT "
    sql += "  SalOrder.IDOrder "
    sql += ", SalOrder.IsClose "
    sql += ", SalOrder.IsConfirm "
    sql += ", SalOrder.IDUser "
    sql += ", SalOrder.Created "
    sql += "FROM SalOrder "
    sql += "WHERE "
    sql += "IsConfirm = ? "
    sql += "ORDER BY SalOrder.IDOrder ASC "

    rs, err := db.Query(sql, param...)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    defer rs.Close()

    // create a fieldbinding object.
    var fArr []string
    fb := fieldbinding.NewFieldBinding()

    if fArr, err = rs.Columns(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    fb.PutFields(fArr)

    //
    outArr := []interface{}{}

    for rs.Next() {
        if err := rs.Scan(fb.GetFieldPtrArr()...); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        fmt.Printf("Row: %v, %v, %v, %s\n", fb.Get("IDOrder"), fb.Get("IsConfirm"), fb.Get("IDUser"), fb.Get("Created"))
        outArr = append(outArr, fb.GetFieldArr())
    }

    if err := rs.Err(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return outArr, nil
}
```

**fieldbinding package:**

```
package fieldbinding

import (
    "sync"
)

// NewFieldBinding ...
func NewFieldBinding() *FieldBinding {
    return &FieldBinding{}
}

// FieldBinding is deisgned for SQL rows.Scan() query.
type FieldBinding struct {
    sync.RWMutex // embedded.  see http://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types
    FieldArr     []interface{}
    FieldPtrArr  []interface{}
    FieldCount   int64
    MapFieldToID map[string]int64
}

func (fb *FieldBinding) put(k string, v int64) {
    fb.Lock()
    defer fb.Unlock()
    fb.MapFieldToID[k] = v
}

// Get ...
func (fb *FieldBinding) Get(k string) interface{} {
    fb.RLock()
    defer fb.RUnlock()
    // TODO: check map key exist and fb.FieldArr boundary.
    return fb.FieldArr[fb.MapFieldToID[k]]
}

// PutFields ...
func (fb *FieldBinding) PutFields(fArr []string) {
    fCount := len(fArr)
    fb.FieldArr = make([]interface{}, fCount)
    fb.FieldPtrArr = make([]interface{}, fCount)
    fb.MapFieldToID = make(map[string]int64, fCount)

    for k, v := range fArr {
        fb.FieldPtrArr[k] = &fb.FieldArr[k]
        fb.put(v, int64(k))
    }
}

// GetFieldPtrArr ...
func (fb *FieldBinding) GetFieldPtrArr() []interface{} {
    return fb.FieldPtrArr
}

// GetFieldArr ...
func (fb *FieldBinding) GetFieldArr() map[string]interface{} {
    m := make(map[string]interface{}, fb.FieldCount)

    for k, v := range fb.MapFieldToID {
        m[k] = fb.FieldArr[v]
    }

    return m
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you really want a map, which is needed in some cases, have a look at dbr, but you need to use the fork (since the pr got rejected in the original repo). The fork seems more up to date anyway:

https://github.com/mailru/dbr

For info on how to use it:

https://github.com/gocraft/dbr/issues/83

Comment: This should have been a comment rather than an answer, since it just recommends a tool rather than answering OP's question.

Answer (score -1):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/bobby96333/goSqlHelper"
)

func main(){
    fmt.Println("hello")
    conn,err :=goSqlHelper.MysqlOpen("user:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/dbname")
    checkErr(err)
    row,err := conn.QueryRow("select * from table where col1 = ? and  col2 = ?","123","abc")
    checkErr(err)
    if *row==nil {
        fmt.Println("no found row")
    }else{
        fmt.Printf("%+v",row)
    }
}

func checkErr(err error){
    if err!=nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

output:

```
&map[col1:abc col2:123]
```

Comment: Wouldn't this throw an error?
Assignment mismatch: 2 variables, but QueryRow returns only one?

Comment: What does this code do? Good answers not only provide the answer to OP's question, but they explain any code used to do so. Uncommented/undescribed blocks of code are dangerous and rarely useful.