# Are there any solution for SELECT * FROM in golang SQL drivers

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

I tried googling a lot & also looked at stackoverflow and to my surprise none has raised this question.

Is there a way to convert the output of SQL SELECT statement's (especially `SELECT * FROM`) result into an array or some kind of map to be utilized in the code.

E.g., `SELECT * FROM table1`, without really knowing the fields can we scan and get an array / map?

What is possible & I know is, e.g., `SELECT name, age FROM table1` & using the below statements will retrieve `name` & `age`.

```
temp_result, _ :=db.Query('SELECT name, age FROM table1')
for temp_result.Next() {
    m_name, m_age := "", ""
    err := result.Scan(&m_name, &m_age)
    if err != nil {
       log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(m_name, m_age)
}
```

Or any other alternatives to handle this ?

Comment: here is Your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840963/create-a-map-in-golang-from-database-rows

Comment: If you don't want to use one of those packages it is fairly straightforward to come up with your own solution using the [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package.

Comment: It is certainly not "fairly straightforward". Value types, pointer types, nested structs, byte arrays, time.Time, custom types, etc: you'll likely have to handle all of those cases and the reflect package can be brittle (panics if you mess it up). https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx has been around for a while and solves this.