# In Go sqlx, how can I fetch all rows in a slice of slices (not maps)?

Tags: go, sqlx

<sup>*This is not a duplicate of [Create a Map in Golang from database Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840963/create-a-map-in-golang-from-database-rows). That question is about reading rows as maps; this question is about reading rows as slices. A map will not work as order needs to be preserved.*</sup>

How can I use sqlx to get a slice of slices that represents all rows and columns in a query? **Not a slice of maps, but a slice of slices**, similar to what Python's `cursor.fetchall()` returns.

I am currently doing this:

```
var results []interface{}
for rows.Next() {
    cols, err := rows.SliceScan()
    checkErr(err)
    results = append(results, cols)
}
```

I see this example in the documentation:

```
var names []string
err = db.Select(&names, "SELECT name FROM place LIMIT 10")
```

which returns a slice of strings.

How can I combine these to to receive a slice of slices, something like this (non-working) example?

```
results := make([][]interface{}, 0)
err := db.Select(&results, "select * from foo")
// panic: non-struct dest type slice with >1 columns (5)
```

Comment: @blackgreen Ah, I missed that part. Then the fix should be replaced `var results []interface{}` with `results := make([][]interface{}, 0)`. I'm ok to leave this as closed now. Thank you!

Comment: @blackgreen, I think you are misunderstanding.  I'm not trying to read a slice of structs (what the referenced question asks, but a slice of slices.  Can you please undupe?

Comment: @ZekeLu, you are correct in that this is not a duplicate... I'm trying to read slices, not structs.  Sadly, the fix in your comment doesn't fix the problem, although it seems to be a correct replacement for creating the slice of slices.

Comment: @MarkHarrison See this demo https://go.dev/play/p/hqb_GkmpsBL, the output is `[][]interface {}{[]interface {}{"a", 1}, []interface {}{"b", 2}, []interface {}{"c", 3}}`. Isn't this what you want?

Comment: @ZekeLu, thanks for this full example.  No problem reading row by row, but I 'm hoping I can fetch the entire results set without having to iterate over all of them, similar to python fetchall() which returns [(1,2,3},(4,5,6)] etc.  That's what Select() does, but seemingly only for known data types, and not for a tuple of varying size.

Comment: @MarkHarrison The doc for [Select](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx#Select) explicitly states that it calls `StructScan`. So it does not work. It's very  easy to wrap the iteration in your own `fetchall` func, so it's not a big deal.

Comment: @ZekeLu, For me the main consideration is performance... the same code runs several times faster in Python, and I'm suspecting it's because there is either less data copying, or the data copying is being done at a lower level down in the C dbapi interface.  Other than that, your solution is perfect... if you make it into an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @MarkHarrison as the error message suggests, you can’t scan directly into interfaces. You can scan into structs, which is what the dupe is about. If you must scan into a slice of interfaces, you have to implement the sqlx scanner interface

Comment: @blackgreen, note that I asked a question about reading a slice of slices.  The apparent answer is "that is not supported".  This is a different question (with a different answer) than how to read a slice of structs.  The irony is that there is a simple answer ("it can't be done") that is revealed in the comments, when it should be an answer.  The question was closed in error, and you should unclose it.

Comment: @MarkHarrison Regarding performance in this case, `pgx` is better than `sqlx`. See the benchmark test here: https://go.dev/play/p/IOTvP2QwvGw. I don't know how you compare the Go implementation with the Python implementation. If you calculated the duration with `time go run .` then it's not fair.